# swatches with infinite scroll for category pages

Tags: ajax, swatches, list.phtml

I am creating an infinite scroll for category pages in magento 1.9.2.

the crux of it is

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: pageurl+'p='+next, 
        success: function(result){
            jQuery('#page_' + next).html(jQuery(result).find('.products-grid'));
        }
    });
```

the problem I am having is when a product with configurable swatches is loaded the swatches do not work.

any ideas how to work around this